# sprintf in C (pointer to an array of char elements)

Tags: c, pointers

I am a newbie in C, and I want to do something like

```
    uint8_t message[12];

    message[0] = 0x00;
    message[1] = 0x00;
    message[2] = 0x00;
    message[3] = 0x00;
    message[4] = 0x00;
    message[5] = 0x00;
    message[6] = 0x00;
    message[7] = 0x00;
    message[8] = 0x00;
    message[9] = 0x00;
    message[10] = 0x00;
    message[11] = 0x00;

sprintf(_smess,"AT$SS=%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",
                            message[0], message[1], message[2], message[3],
                            message[4], message[5], message[6], message[7],
                            message[8], message[9], message[10], message[11]);
```

But I don't know how to declare the variable _smess, I've tried with char *_smess or uint8_t _smess[12] but I got an error anyway

if a declare `char _smess[43];` then I got this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sprintf' [enabled by 
     default]
    - implicit declaration of function 'sprintf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    - each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it 
     appears in
    - '_smess' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: with `uint8_t message[12] = { 0 };` you don't need the following 12 lines that initialize each array element.

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada it should be `char _smess[43];` as answered below - it needs a `nul` terminator.

Comment: `implicit declaration of function 'sprintf'` means that you haven't included the correct header. (`#include <stdio.h>`)

Comment: 42 is to few! @WeatherVane

Comment: "*implicit declaration*" you seem to miss the relevant prototype.

Comment: a prototype is an include ?

Comment: The prototype is in an included library header file.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've just edited along the lines of the answer's OP who stated _"make sure to leave room ..."_. Originally it was `50`, I just did some optimization to make the answer more concise.

Comment: @WeatherVane That might be coming up implementation dependent. Safest portable way is to ask for results of `sprintf()` with a `NULL` pointer passed beforehand, and allocate the buffer after that (may be using VLA Compiler extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how big the string is based on the format string passed to `sprintf` (i.e. 42 characters), so declare a char array of at least that size, making sure to leave room for the NUL (`'\0'`) terminator:

```
char _smess[43];
```

Edit:

The error "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sprintf'" is because you didn't `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your file.

The "'_smess' undeclared" error is most likely because you didn't define it before it was used.  It needs to appear before the `sprintf` call.

Comment: `snprintf` should be preferred when it exists - throw away buffer overflow risks...

Answer (score 0):

int sprintf( char* buffer, const char* format, ... );

each character we have to allocate memory... In your case 
"AT$SS=" required 6 bytes,
%02x required 2bytes
empty space between each charcter required 1byte
Total bytes required is 6 + 24 + 11 =41 bytes.
Allocate memory by static variable char _smess[41] or dynamic allocation char *_smess = new char[41]; unsigned char will not accepted